# Does Adobe Photoshop CS (version 8) run on Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, compatibility

A friend has a Mac that’s still running Tiger (Mac OS X 10.4). She has Photoshop CS (version 8.0) on it. She needs to upgrade the Mac to Leopard or Snow Leopard to allow installation of iTunes 10, because she has an iPhone 3GS now.

Does Adobe Photoshop CS (version 8) run on Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6)? I.e. if I upgrade the Mac to Snow Leopard, will Photoshop CS still run okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does run, but Snow Leopard does not install Rosetta by default. Rosetta is needed to run PowerPC applications on Intel Macs.

You can install Rosetta from the Snow Leopard disk. I believe you will be prompted to do this when you try to run Photoshop.

Comment: Presumably this means she has an intel iMac. I strongly recommend upgrading to a newer version of Photoshop (or perhaps Photoshop Elements), as running an Intel-native version will be much faster.

Comment: @Paul: she sure does, and it seems to run plenty fast enough for her needs through Rosetta.